# Stuck with the post function for flask for form

Tags: python, html, flask

starting to learn python with flask. I've been stuck with this component for days and tried different solutions but couldn't really pass this.

I've packaged the application under website through **init**.py and has a main.py file. I have a separate webpage for the form and the output file and when I try to submit the form nothing happens and if I try to go to the url for the output it will generate this problem.

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vBsbO.png)

Here's the code for the **views.py **

I can just access the /pdf if I delete

*number=formData["modelNumber"]*

```
from flask import Blueprint, render_template, request, redirect, url_for

views = Blueprint('views', __name__)

formData = {}

@views.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template("home.html")

@views.route('/localization-brief', methods=["Post", "Get"])
def localizationbrief():
    if request.method == "Post":

        modelNumber = request.form("mnumber")


        formData["modelNumber"] = modelNumber

        return redirect(url_for('pdf'))
    else:

        return render_template("localizationbrief.html")

@views.route('/pdf')
def pdf():
    return render_template("pdf.html", number=formData["modelNumber"])
```

Then for the** main.py**

```
from website import create_app

app = create_app()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Here's the code for the **form**.

```
<form class="row g-3 needs-validation" method="Post" novalidate>
    <!--model number-->
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <label for="mnumber" class="form-label">Model number</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="mnumber" value="" name="mnumber">
      <div class="invalid-feedback">
        Please type the model number.
      </div>
    </div>
```

Finally for the **output file**

```
</tr>
<tr class="content">
<td class="font-weight-bold">Brand: {{ brand }}  
                                    <br>Group: {{ group }} 
                                    <br>Type: {{ type }}</td>
                                <td class="font-weight-bold">Model number: {{ number }} <br> Source: {{ source }} <br> {{ style }} </td> </tr>
```

Thanks.

I tried changing the syntax for the codes and different variations.

Answer (score 0):

A KeyError states that the requested key is not contained in the dict.

As a hint:

- The request method is returned in upper case.
- The form data can be retrieved as if from a dict.

Instead of using a global variable, the data is passed to the second endpoint via URL parameters in the example.

```py
from flask import (
    Blueprint, 
    redirect, 
    render_template, 
    request, 
    url_for
)

views = Blueprint('views', __name__)

@views.route('/localization-brief', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def localizationbrief():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        modelNumber = request.form.get('mnumber')
        if modelNumber:
            return redirect(url_for('.pdf', model=modelNumber))

    return render_template('localizationbrief.html')

@views.route('/pdf')
def pdf():
    modelNumber = request.args.get('model')
    if not modelNumber:
        return redirect(url_for('.localizationbrief'))

    return render_template('pdf.html', number=modelNumber)
```